# How do I change the fill color for a computed variable in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to change the default fill color from blue to green or red. 
Here is the code I am using

```
Top_pos<- ggplot(Top_10, aes(x=reorder(Term,Cs), y=Cs, fill=pvalue)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour="black") + coord_flip()
```

Using the above code, I get the following image.  I have no problem with this data but I do not know how to change the fill color.

[image: bar plot with current colors]

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to confuse scaling the color and scaling the fill. In the case of `geom_bar`/`geom_col`, color changes the borders around the bars while fill changes the colors inside the bars.

You already have the code that's necessary to scale fill color by value: `aes(fill = pvalue)`. The part you're missing is a `scale_fill_*` command. There are several options; some of the more common for continuous scales are `scale_fill_gradient` or `scale_fill_distiller`. Some packages also export palettes and scale functions to make it easy to use them, such as the last example which uses a scale from the `rcartocolor` package.

`scale_fill_gradient` lets you set endpoints for a gradient; `scale_fill_gradient2` and `scale_fill_gradientn` let you set multiple midpoints for a gradient.

`scale_fill_distiller` interpolates ColorBrewer palettes, which were designed for discrete data, into a continuous scale.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
Top_10 <- tibble(
    Term = letters[1:10],
    Cs = runif(10),
    pvalue = rnorm(10, mean = 0.05, sd = 0.005)
)

plt <- ggplot(Top_10, aes(x = reorder(Term, Cs), y = Cs, fill = pvalue)) +
    geom_col(color = "black") +
    coord_flip()

plt + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "purple")
```

[image]

```r
plt + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Greens")
```

[image]

```r
plt + rcartocolor::scale_fill_carto_c(palette = "Sunset")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm a fan of [R Color Brewer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/RColorBrewer.pdf).  It's got a set of built-in palettes that play well together for qualitative, sequential or diverging data types.  Check out [colorbrewer2.org](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=BuGn&n=3) for some examples on real-ish data

More generally, and for how to actually code it, you can always add a `scale_fill_manual` argument.  There are some built-ins in `ggplot2` for gradients [(examples here)](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html)

Comment: I have tried that but it won't change the interior color. Only changes the outline of the bars. I will give it another try - thanks!

Comment: One of you two should post the code!!!!! At the moment this looks like a link only answer.